# Может ли модератор закрывать вопросы с развёрнутым ответом и ставить минусы?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Помните эту тему?
[Что делать, если модератор под надуманным предлогом закрывает все мои вопросы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11860/)

В общем, история получила продолжение.
После несправедливого закрытия этого вопроса: [Сокращение minmax( ) в Grid Layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371520/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-minmax-%d0%b2-grid-layout?noredirect=1#comment2435180_1371520)

Grundy взялся за старое, в данном вопросе я получил ответ и написал коммент к ответу.
Он снова (2 раз подряд) закрыл данный вопрос и почистил неугодные ему комменты под ответом, и под вопросом. Вдобавок к этому, он наставил минусов вопросу.
Вопрос снова был закрыт с формулировкой **Этот вопрос не по теме.**
Как данный вопрос может быть не по теме, если этот ресурс был специально создан для таких тем.

Закрывать вопросы с развёрнутым ответом и ставить минусы это приемлемое поведение для модератора?

Comment: Пожалуйста перестаньте давать вопросам эмоциональные заголовки не отражающие их суть.

Comment: #СкажемGrundyУходи  %)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почитал истории переписки по ссылке. Вот что имею сказать:

1. Комменты под ответом не несут полезной информации и должны быть удалены. Иногда их удаляет бот по какой-то хитрой регулярке, но часто требуется вмешательство человека.
2. Комменты под вопросом - не по теме вопроса. Их следовало удалить, что и было сделано.
3. Закрывать вопросы, даже имеющие ответ - нормальная практика. Например для случаев, если есть дубликат с очень подробным ответом.
4. Стоило ли закрывать вопрос в данном случае - не уверен. Я не спец по css, но на мой непрофессиональный взгляд вопрос - норм.
5. Переходить на личности, в т.ч. с упоминанием конкретных участников - плохая идея. Как именно можно жаловаться на действия модераторов - вам в прошлом вашем вопросе сообщали.
6. Подозревать по малейшему поводу людей в троллинге, ИМХО - признак троллинга. Лично мне, как человеку, это не нравится.

Comment: Переходить на личности, в т.ч. с упоминанием конкретных участников - плохая идея. Как именно можно жаловаться на действия модераторов - вам в прошлом вашем вопросе сообщали. Ну а как называть данного участника, назову модер люди не поймут, ведь модеров много.

Comment: По ссылке - видно кто с вами разговаривал. В общем случае - не важно какой именно модератор имелся в виду, если суть проблемы - закрытый вопрос. Т.к. вопрос может не только модератор закрыть, но и человек с золотым знаком или 5 человек с правом голоса за закрытие.

Comment: Так придет Grundy и снова все закроет, он уже сделал это 2 раза к моему вопросу

Comment: Ставить минусы все могут и, надеюсь, эту фичу никогда не уберут, а то будет как на тытрубе - кнопка есть, а минусов - нет.

Comment: Ну а как тут задавать вопросы, ведь я даже не успеваю получить ответы. Приходит Grundy и закрывает вопрос под любым предлогом примерно через 3-10 минут после открытия вопроса. Разве это не троллинг?

Comment: 2 раза это, кмк, ещё не система. Если вам действительно важно открыть вопрос - задайте тут, на мете вопрос с предложением проголосовать в виде голосов на ответах надо ли его переоткрыть.  Возможно, сообщество решит это сделать.

Comment: А если Grundy снова закроет вопрос? Сколько тут сижу, сколько модеров видел, ни разу не сталкивался с такой проблемой, пока не пришел Grundy.

Comment: Возможно, вы его как человека обидели обвинениями в троллинге? И он после этого формально корректно закрывает вопросы? У меня, к сожалению, нет времени подробно вникать в каждый конкретный случай, но, если подобное ещё раза 2-3 произойдёт - я лично вопросы переоткрою, если буду полностью убеждён, что они закрыты абсолютно безосновательно. Вам же стоит внимательнее прислушиваться к советам в комментах - очень сложно помогать кому-то, если он не говорит пробовал ли совет и какой получил результат. Правильный ли синтаксис - тоже сложно иногда сказать. Порой программисты его лишь примерно помнят

Comment: Так все началось да этого, он много раз закрывал мои вопросы под разными предлогами, я долго терпел, ничего ему не говорил. Но после бана(не могу задавать новые вопросы) я решил, что хватит молчать.

Comment: Спасибо, но как снять бан, чтобы задать новые вопросы.

Comment: Я вижу меньше 5 закрытий, в т.ч. закрытия вопросов по js, где у человека есть золотая метка. Т.е. всё ещё не вижу систематического закрытия по личным причинам. Низкое качество вопросов - вижу. Вам стоит задавать более конкретные вопросы и не повторять их, а править старые. Бан сам по себе со временем пройдёт. Он автоматически выдан системой из-за минусов на вопросах, скорее всего (код выдачи бана на вопросы не видел - точнее не скажу)

Comment: Золотая метка это кто или что? Модератор?

Comment: Золотая метка выдаётся за много голосов за сообщения по к-л метке. Даёт возможность закрывать вопросы как дубликаты. Своего рода выданный сообществом кредит доверия по определённой теме. Доступен не только моераторам.

Comment: ну вот посмотрите, собрал Grundy свою команду и при помощи неё все равно закрыл вопрос Сокращение minmax( ) в Grid Layout.